# How to copy text before the ellipses textview Android

Tags: android, textview, clipboardmanager

I have a **multi-line** TextView in Android which has a copy option on long press.

When the user presses on copy, this is the cody I execute:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Answer", tv_answer.getText().toString().trim() + "");
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

My TextView holds text like - "**this is a long text which spans all of three lines**" and shows "**this is a long ...**" because I've set `android:ellipsize="end"`.

The problem is, `tv_answer.getText()` will return the whole text that I'm setting to my TextView. I only need the text before the ellipses.

I need some guidance with using `tv_answer.getLayout().getEllipsisCount()` or `tv_answer.getLayout().getEllipsisStart()` or something similar to only get the text before the ellipses.

Comment: Try standard method:  To enable the standard copy/paste for TextView, U can choose one of the following:
Change in layout file: add below property to your TextView. android:textIsSelectable="true"
In your Java class write this line to set it programmatically. myTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion but I need to show a custom dialog for copying as per the UI of my app, so it needs to be a by handling a longClick event.